# simple algorithm with scala

Tags: algorithm, scala

Very simple algorithm in scala

```
  def listReplication(num: Int, arr: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    val l = new ListBuffer[Int]()
    for (a <- arr.indices) {
      for (b <- 1 to num) {
        l += arr.apply(a)
      }
    }
    l.toList
  }
```

1. Can it writes in immutable ?
2. Cannot use recursion

Thanks

Comment: it would be easier if you told us what should this method do. and you should try by yourself first, present us what have you achieved, and then we can help you. this way it seems we are doing your homework

Answer (score 2):

Cat skinning one-liner

```
def listReplication(num: Int, arr: List[Int]):List[Int] = 
  arr.flatMap(a=>List.fill(num)(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for { ... } yield` [syntax](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) to traverse any collection (or Cartesian product of collections)  and produce a new collection, with no mutable data:

```
def listReplication(num: Int, arr: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  for {
    a <- arr
    b <- 1 to num
  } yield a
}
```